# How can I create and populate a new ID column

Tags: mysql, sql

I got an `ID` column that is not auto incremented, so my `ID`s are not uniform and a mess. I need to create a new `ID` field and populate it with `ID`s 1-max rows.

I am not sure how to create one. I tried something trivial but I get errors about it being null when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Could this [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829400/adding-id-auto-increment-after-table-exist) you ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
declare @rn := 0;

update table t
    set newid = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    order by id;
```

You might have to add the column first:

```
alter table t add column newid int;
```

Comment: Can't run this query. is it mysql?

Comment: @code578841441 . . . The code is definitely MySQL.  Of course, where it says "table" you should put in the table you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Hash the current ids as Keys in a HashMap and for each new key, the value should be 1 plus previous value. (Or you can set a i++ like counter for each new row).  These values can act as your new ID.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, As soon as you create an identity column automatically, the column is populated with values from 1 to n.

Answer (score -2):

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ADD RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ADD COLUMN Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY Id(Id)
```

This would add a extra identity column to your table.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Is this mysql syntax? It says `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTITY(1,1)' at line 1`